# Adding dictionary values to a list, which is a value to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Im having a python dictionary which has value field as list.
I want to append to dictionary values to each list based on the key value.
How do i do it? I have one sample dictionary which i iterate and get values to append to the list. The code i wrote somehow seem to add all values in the sample dict to all key values in the dict im appending values to.
What am i doing wrong?

```
default_value = []
a = dict.fromkeys(li, default_value)
for key, value in data.items():
    if key == "items":
        for val in value:
            a[val['owner']['display_name']].append(val)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3], [])
```

creates a dictionary:

```
{1: [],
 2: [],
 3: []}
```

where all values point to the same dictionary.

```
a[1].append(5)

{1: [5],
 2: [5],
 3: [5]}
```

You have to create the dictionary in a real loop:

```
a = {k: [] for k in li}
```

Your code snippet could be written as:

```
a = {k: [] for k in li}
for val in data['items']:
    a[val['owner']['display_name']].append(val)
```

Comment: In your shortened code snippet, `val` is not defined. The outer `for` loop is not necessary, but I think the inner loop _is_ needed.

Comment: that worked.have been breaking my head for a while. Could you explain why it behaves this way as in why does a[1].append(5) change all values?

Comment: @user3340996 - because a list is a mutable object. It may have many pointers and all can modify its attributes (such as elements).